# How to return a result if user doesn't click on message box

Tags: c#, multithreading

**Background**: I want to show a custom message box to the user with Yes/No buttons and if the user clicks each of these buttons I will return the result to the caller. Also, if the user doesn't show any reaction again I want to return a third result (using a `Timer` event). **In a word**, either after some time elapsed or after a button click the method (`Display` in my code) should return a value; and I want to wait for either of them to happen.

**Problem**: The UI looks frozen and only the `Timer` event triggers.

**Code** which will be used in the real project (with descent names!):

```
namespace MessageBox
{
    public partial class Form2 : Form
    {
        public Form2()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MyForm.Display();
        }
    }
    public class MyForm : Form
    {
        public MyForm()
        {
             List<Button> _buttonCollection = new List<Button>();

            FlowLayoutPanel _flpButtons = new FlowLayoutPanel();
            Panel _plFooter = new Panel();

            _plFooter.Dock = DockStyle.Bottom;
            _plFooter.Padding = new Padding(5);
            _plFooter.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(41, 47, 139);
            _plFooter.Height = 75;
            this.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None;
            this.BackColor = Color.FromArgb(20, 37, 105);
            this.StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;
            this.Padding = new Padding(3);
            this.Width = 400;
            _flpButtons.FlowDirection = FlowDirection.RightToLeft;
            _flpButtons.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
            _plFooter.Controls.Add(_flpButtons);
            this.Controls.Add(_plFooter);
            Button btnYes = new Button();
            btnYes.Click += ButtonClick;
            btnYes.Text = "Yes";
            Button btnNo = new Button();
            btnNo.Click += ButtonClick;
            btnNo.Text = "No";
            _buttonCollection.Add(btnYes);
            _buttonCollection.Add(btnNo);
            foreach (Button btn in _buttonCollection)
            {
                btn.ForeColor = Color.FromArgb(170, 170, 170);
                btn.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Eurostile", 12, FontStyle.Bold);
                btn.Padding = new Padding(3);
                btn.FlatStyle = FlatStyle.Flat;
                btn.Height = 60;
                btn.Width = 150;
                btn.FlatAppearance.BorderColor = Color.FromArgb(99, 99, 98);
                _flpButtons.Controls.Add(btn);
            }


        }
        static Task taskA;
        private  void ButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            _event.Set();
            Button btn = (Button)sender;
            if (btn.Text == "Yes")
                Result = 1;
            else
            {
                Result = 2;
            }
            this.Close();
            this.Dispose();
        }
        static AutoResetEvent _event = new AutoResetEvent(false);
        private static MyForm form;
        public static int Display()
        {
            form = new MyForm();
            StartTimer();
            form.Show();
            _event.WaitOne();
            form.Close();
            form.Dispose();
            return Result;
        }

        private static void StartTimer()
        {
            _timer = new System.Timers.Timer(10000);
            _timer.Elapsed += SetEvent;

            _timer.AutoReset = false;
            _timer.Enabled = true;
        }

        private static System.Timers.Timer _timer;
        public static int Result { get; set; }

        private static void SetEvent(Object source, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            _timer.Start();
            Result = -1;
            var timer = (System.Timers.Timer) source;
            timer.Elapsed -= SetEvent;
            _event.Set();
        }
    }
}
```

**Note**: I know the problem is that the UI control is created in a thread which is frozen but what's the solution?

Comment: Mok, I think this is what you want. Check [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14522540/close-a-messagebox-after-several-seconds) for the answer.

Comment: @MarcLyon Actually, when I was implementing this code, I looked at that code, first of all it uses hooks which I don't want to use (though I tried and it made things too complicated), secondly, there the SO doesn't need to return a value if the UI is idle.

Answer (score 2):

Create a Dialog for `MessageBox` at the end of your process and show the alert you want to show the user.

You can look at the sources [like](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6932792/how-to-create-a-custom-messagebox) and issue with [Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19856017/messagebox-show-freezes-execution-windows-form-c-sharp)