# Modification of Utility Method to Support Multi-Threading

Tags: c#, multithreading, winforms, dialog

I have been given a application to multi-thread and this has been done. All message boxes in this application are correctly called by a single `static` method in a utility class. This method is:

```
public static void ErrMsg(String strMsg, Exception ex = null)
{
    ...
    if (ex == null)
        MessageBox.Show(strMsg, "MyApp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
    ...
}
```

Clearly this does not provide the `IWin32Window` owner and this is now causing me a problem when I invoke an error message from a background thread-pool thread using this method. The problem is a known one of the message box showing behind my main form. See:

1. [Popping a MessageBox for the main app with Backgroundworker in WPF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3104661/popping-a-messagebox-for-the-main-app-with-backgroundworker-in-wpf)

et al. I could pass in the `SynchronisationContext` of the current thread to `ErrMsg` and do

```
synchronizationContext.Send(callback => 
    MessageBox.Show("Some error message for the user"), null);
```

But there are 700+ calls to this method, the majority of which are on the UI thread and do not cause a problem. My question is: **how can I amend the `ErrMsg` method so that my message box appears in front reguardless of the current `SynchronisationContex` and without having to ammend all 700+ calls to the method?**

Thanks for your time.

---

**Edit.** @Dmitry's idea was great. However, if the active form does not have focus or is an MdiChild form then the `Form.ActiveForm` will return null. To get around this I use `Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Last()` to get the last active form, beit MdiChild or whatever. The code is now...

```
Form activeForm = Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Last();
if (ex == null)
{
    activeForm.Invoke(new ShowErrMsg(text => 
        MessageBox.Show(activeForm, 
            text, 
            "UserCost",
            MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
            MessageBoxIcon.Warning)), 
        strMsg);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the **Form.ActiveForm** static property as a first argument for MessageBox.Show(...). Also the thread-safe invocation should be used.
Example:

```
private delegate void ShowErrMsgMethod(string text);

public static void ErrMsg(String strMsg, Exception ex = null)
{
    ...
    if (ex == null)
    {
        Form activeForm = Form.ActiveForm ?? Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Last();
        activeForm.Invoke(new ShowErrMsgMethod(text => MessageBox.Show(activeForm, text, "MyApp", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning)), strMsg);
    }
    ...
}
```

**EDIT:** Improved for a circumstances when other forms are opened. The reference to main form was eliminated.
**EDIT2:** Improved for a circumstances when `Form.ActiveForm == null`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. This looks like a decent approach and I have thought of this before; however, other forms other than the main form call this method - the question is will this cause a problem? One thing that concerns me is if the main form launches a sub-form and this form calls `ErrMsg`... Thanks again I will implement and test this tomorrow.

Comment: I've updated the example for circumstances when other forms are opened.  
The solution is to use the **Form.ActiveForm** static property as a MessageBox owner.

Comment: Damn. Fair play. I will check this out tomorrow. I am impressed by the knowledge of a newcomer! Did not know `Form` had this static method. Thanks for your help...

Comment: This is a great idea, however, if the top form does not have focus or is an MdiChild, `Form.ActiveForm` will return null. I have amended the code to suit. See my edited question. Feel free to copy into your answer...

Comment: It makes sense to use both `Form.ActiveForm` and, if the one is null - last `Application.OpenForms`:  

    `Form activeForm = Form.ActiveForm ?? Application.OpenForms.Cast<Form>().Last();`  

Reason: the order of the `Application.OpenForms` array is undefined, and there is no guarantee that the last form is now active. For example, you can open `Form1` and `Form2` without setting the owner in `Show()` method, and then switch between them in UI. But the last form will always be the same - `Form2`.